# Can I put empty line between sibling elements as a VS Code setting?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, markup, emmet

I recently started using VS Code, I did my best to research how to put empty line between sibling elements in html automatically through VS options without the need of putting it manually, but nothing. The following snippet triggers when I type "tabs" and hit `tab`.

Current result:

```
 <div class="tabs js-tabs">
    <div class="tabs__head">
        <div class="tabs__nav"></div><!-- /.tabs__nav -->
    </div><!-- /.tabs__head -->
    <div class="tabs__body">
        <div class="tab"></div><!-- /.tab -->
    </div><!-- /.tabs__body -->
</div><!-- /.tabs js-tabs -->
```

Desired result:

```
<div class="tabs js-tabs">
    <div class="tabs__head">
        <div class="tabs__nav"></div><!-- /.tabs__nav -->
    </div><!-- /.tabs__head -->

    <div class="tabs__body">
        <div class="tab"></div><!-- /.tab -->
    </div><!-- /.tabs__body -->
</div><!-- /.tabs js-tabs -->
```

Comment: You can put newlines into snippets as `\n`.  You should show your snippet in the question.

Comment: I know I can but the idea is when I type ul>li*3 to expand following the same logic. I want it all to happen automatically

Comment: If your question is specifically about snippet expansions / emmet, please [edit] to make that clear in your post.

Comment: How much more clear should my question be? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert empty text node `{}` so Emmet will format it as newline:

`.tabs>.tabs_head+{}+.tabs_body`

expands to the following result in Sublime Text:

```html
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tabs_head"></div>
    
    <div class="tabs_body"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The think is I would like to have it as a vs setting without the need to add it manually

Comment: How can you describe this setting?